# ¿Usar como patrón de texto a reemplazar en un archivo, texto de otro archivo?

Tags: cmd, sed

tengo el archivo ejemplo1.txt de 5 lineas:

```
angélica
maría
juliana
elisa
rosa
```

y tengo otro archivo ejemplo2.txt

```
pedro
juliana
pablo
juliana
carlos
```

y quiero que el archivo ejemplo2.txt quede:

```
pedro
andres
pablo
andres
carlos
```

algo así como:

`sed "s/usar el texto en la linea 3 (juliana) del archivo ejemplo1.txt/y reemplazar las coincidencias por andres en el archivo/g" ejemplo2.txt`

creen que se pueda especificar como patrón de texto a reemplazar, texto de otro archivo?

quiero lograr esto en batch de windows si es posible o con sed

Comment: No veo cómo se usa el archivo1, pues allí no hay ninguna referencia a "andres"

Comment: Esta lógica sería bueno explicarla. Cambiar todos los nombres de archivo1 por andres? Nombres exactos o solo parecidos? Dale a [edit] para detallarlo

Comment: Si te registras en el sitio podrás eliminar la pregunta. Dicho lo cual, los comentarios que dejé son en base a haber respondido muuuuchas preguntas similares que, a veces, y por no ser del todo claras, mutan en debates demsiado largos sobre cómo interpretar y mejorar la solución. Recomiendon leer [ask] y [mcve], así como detallar si cosas como "línea 3" puede variar o bien es algo fijo (no es lo mismo `sed 's/juliana/andres/'` que `sed 's/^juliana$/andres/g'`, por ejemplo)